# std::sort & comp - calling convention?

Tags: c++, sorting, calling-convention

> Windows targeted project,
>   Visual Studio 2012

I'm trying to use [std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) to sort an array of struct pointers. The sorting is meant to be done from a GUID contained within the struct, and so I want to define a custom compare function for my sort call.

```
std::sort(
    std::begin(pUnits),
    std::end(pUnits),
    MyCustomSortFunctionHere
);
```

Now my question is, what's the expected calling convention for the provided compare function? Question rather could be, does the calling convention even make a difference here?

Reason I need to know is, my project settings play with the default calling conventions and so if I declare my compare function without explicitly declaring the calling convention, I'm wondering if it would break. Can't seem to find any information about this anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `std::sort` won't care about the calling convention of `MyCustomSortFunctionHere`. It's a template, it'll take anything that a function call operator can be applied to.

Comment: Some examples are here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

Comment: @HariomSingh those do not define any calling convention, that's the core point of my question

Comment: There is a example // sort using a custom function object
    struct {
        bool operator()(int a, int b) const
        {   
            return a < b;
        }   
    } customLess;
    std::sort(s.begin(), s.end(), customLess);
    for (auto a : s) {
        std::cout << a << " ";
    }

Comment: @HariomSingh: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention

Comment: Calling conventions are mainly important when the call site is compiled independently from the called function.  E.g., across a library or DLL boundary (though sometimes between separate compilation units - i.e., source files - if the compiler options are sufficiently different).  Anyway, in the case of a template function - `std::sort` here - all the code is compiled at once in the same place and thus whatever declarations are in effect control the outcome.  In short: doesn't matter here or in most of the STL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My reasoning is that `MyCustomSortFunctionHere` function (or class methods?) is called with the calling convention you ask it to: with

```
extern "C" bool MyCustomSortFunctionHere(Unit const*, Unit const*);
```

it would be called with "C" calling convention.
Since `std::sort()` is a template function, it is actually compiled together with your code in its same translation unit, including the part where your comparison function is called, and the call to `MyCustomSortFunctionHere` follows the rules you have specified in that translation unit.

If you are defining the comparison function in the same translation unit, you should get away with not specifying any convention.
If the function is instead defined in a different translation unit, you would need to express to the compiler which is the right calling convention.

Answer (score 1):

How is your MyCustomSortFunctionHere implemented?
a. using functor or,
b. using the method signature bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b)

In case of 1st method "thiscall" calling convention is used and in case of 2nd method __cdecl calling convention is used. 
I verified the above using the dissassembly of the code generated by Visual Studio compiler for each of the above methods.

Hope this helps!